# How to target all controls (WPF Styles)

Tags: wpf, user-interface, styles

Can I specify a style that applies to all elements? I tried

```
<Style TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5" />
</Style>
```

But it did nothing

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The `Style` you created is only targeting `Control` and not elements that derive from `Control`.  When you don't set the `x:Key` it's implicitly set to the `TargetType`, so in your case `x:Key="{x:Type Control}"`.

There isn't any direct way to specify a `Style` that targets all elements that derive from the `TargetType` of the `Style`. You have some other options.

If you have the following `Style`

```
<Style x:Key="ControlBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50" />
</Style>
```

You can target all `Buttons` for example

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ControlBaseStyle}"/>
```

or use the style directly on any element, e.g. `Button`

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ControlBaseStyle}" ...>
```

Comment: I was wondering why my style with a target type of `FrameworkElement` wasn't being applied to all of my controls - this answered that question!

Comment: Is it really that crappy, that I must specify style for all types of controls placed on window, not just for some root thing common for all???

Answer (score 10):

As Fredrik Hedblad answered you can effect all elements that inherited from control.

But you can't apply style for textblock and button with the same style for example.

to do that:

```
    <Style x:Key="DefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}"/>
```