# How to apply style for all control in panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, styles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to target all controls (WPF Styles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131034/how-to-target-all-controls-wpf-styles)

My panel contains many kind of control such as `Button, TextBox`,.. and all of them derived from `Control`. I want to set margin for all of them, I hoped that defining style for `Control` would automatically set property to all controls, but it does not work.

```
<WrapPanel>

    <WrapPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,0,0" />
        </Style>
    </WrapPanel.Resources>

    <Button Content="Button 1" />
    <Button Content="Button 2" />
    <TextBox Width="100" />

</WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, I do not think that is possible :(
Also see:
[How to target all controls (WPF Styles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131034/how-to-target-all-controls-wpf-styles)

There is one small error in your xaml code above, it should say TargetType="{x:Type Control}" for the xaml parser to set a Type object (and not a string).

So you either have to create a style for every control type. 
One more option could be to use style inheritance (based on another style), but I think the number of code lines will be the same.

Hope that helped a little.