# IsFocused property does not sets to true even after clicking over the control

Tags: wpf

I have a grid panel with a user controls as its child element.I need the functionality where i need to change the border brush to some color when user click on the user control i,e i need to change the border brush when control is in focus.I tied to use trigger over is focused property but it did not help.Any help appreciated.

Here is the sample code. where I have two user controls and a style which contains a trigger to change border brush when focused. But it does not do so..

```
 <Window x:Class="DemoAppForBug.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:DemoAppForBug="clr-namespace:DemoAppForBug"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DemoAppForBug:One BorderThickness="5" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Green" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <DemoAppForBug:Two BorderThickness="5" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Green" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @Vivek Are you setting focus programatically or else just mouse over? If it is just mouse over you can use IsMouseOver property instead.

Comment: Do you really set the focus on usercontrol and not on some element inside usercontrol? Is usercontrol focusable? Means is focusable set to true? Leave that ugly green color away and try it out whether one of the usercontrols changes to red.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131034/how-to-target-all-controls-wpf-styles) may help you troubleshoot your problem. By targeting UserControl you wouldn't be setting that behaviour on every derived type.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the green `BorderBrush` inside the style:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DemoAppForBug:One BorderThickness="5" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <DemoAppForBug:Two BorderThickness="5" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```