# How set Style of WPF ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I would like to modify default style of comboBox. So I write this code:

```
        <!-- ComboBox style -->
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" 
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    ClickMode="Press">
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                        Style="{x:Null}"  Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                        Foreground="DarkBlue"
                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup  Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True"  Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid  Name="DropDown"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border  x:Name="DropDownBorder"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

This is my comboBox in XAML file, but I don't know to set my style:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="nomiGiocatori" />
```

How I apply new Stype of this ComboBox?

Reguards

Answer (score 5):

Your style is a bit wrong, it should be

```
<Style x:Key="YourButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

And in your xaml code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="nomiGiocatori" Style="{StaticResource YourButtonStyle}"/>
```

You can apply it to all comboboxes if you define your style as

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="Button"/>
```

Then you don't have to do anything with your xaml.

[This answer describes a similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133971/2285592)

Hope it helps,

Stian

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion but I don't think you can apply a style with a target type Button to ComboBox object. I have reviewed your suggestion and it doesn't work in anywhere in WFP implementation. Even if you use BasedOn="Button" or "ComboBox". The compiler generates the error message TypeConverter for "Style" does not support converting from a string.

ComboBox basically has three sections: ComboBox, ComboBoxItems and ToggleButton elements. To override the default settings, you have to define these three styles first with property type as template and also setting the OverridesDefaultStyle to true.