# textbox styling for all the forms in the project

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Here is the code for the Textbox in one of my form(window1.xaml) here i have applied Textbox.style for the textbox, My requirement is i want to apply this same style for all the textboxes in my project all windows(window2.xaml,window3.xaml,.........)

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" MaxLength="1000" x:Name="txtQuestionDesc" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
             Grid.Row="1"        
             Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="100"  
                     Text="{Binding QuestionText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" >
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        <Label Content="Question Description" Foreground="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                </VisualBrush>
                            </Style.Resources>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131034/how-to-target-all-controls-wpf-styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Style on your App.xaml, it should work

Comment: What do you mean by custom control? If you define it on your App.xaml, it will apply to every Textbox in your application, unless you have defined another style for your Textbox