# Different templates for INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have error object:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represent error in wizard control child.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ErrorContainer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kind"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public ErrorContainer(ErrorKind kind, string message)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message));

        Kind = kind;
        Message = message;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Kind of error.
    /// </summary>
    public ErrorKind Kind { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Text to display.
    /// </summary>
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Message;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Kind of error.
/// </summary>
public enum ErrorKind
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Prevents telegram send.
    /// </summary>
    Critical = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// Only display message.
    /// </summary>
    Warning = 1
}
```

I use INotifyDataErrorInfo and custom style for my text box. I return collection of `ErrorContainer` as INotifyDataErrorInfo errors. I want to show error message only when `ErrorKind` is `Critical`. Here is how i try to do it:

```
<Style x:Key="TextboxWithAdvancedValidationHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentItem.ErrorContent.Kind}" Value="{x:Static kn01:ErrorKind.Critical}">
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
              <Border BorderBrush="Salmon" Background="#11FF0000" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
              </Border>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Polygon  VerticalAlignment="Center" Points="0,4 4,0 4,8" Fill="Salmon" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Salmon" StrokeThickness="2" />
                <Border Background="Salmon" Padding="4" Margin="-1,0,0,0">
                  <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2,-1,0,1" Text="{Binding CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
                </Border>
              </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However it doesn't work at all and use default error template.

Answer (score 2):

Do not put `Validation.ErrorTemplate` template inside Trigger.

`Validation.ErrorTemplate` must be set before the error occurs.

If you want different error templates, use triggers inside ErrorTemplate. Alternatively, you can use `ContentPresenter` with `ContentTemplateSelector`.

```
<Style x:Key="TextboxWithAdvancedValidationHorizontal" TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>

          <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
              <Border BorderBrush="Salmon" Background="#11FF0000" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
              </Border>
            </StackPanel>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="...">
                <!-- add you custom UI logic here -->
              </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>

    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging it with breakpoints to check your bindings? 
Also, I think you're targetting your style in a wrong way. Here another answer that could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133971/6563936

Comment: Im sure that i target my style in wrong way, but i dont understand how should it target it.

Comment: You did add Style="{StaticResource TextboxWithAdvancedValidationHorizontal}" to the TextBox that you want to display the error, right?

Comment: sure i did. Problem is not how i bind control style, but how i bind INotifyDataErrorInfo Errors in inner trigger.

Comment: That's why I asked if you tried to debug it with breakpoints. Set one at a getter and look if it triggers. If you use Visual Studio you can see in the Event log if there are some Binding errors!

Comment: Also, maybe try (Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent.Kind!