# Using WPF how to define a style to set all controls TextOptions.TextFormattingMode?

Tags: wpf

I am aware of answer for [How to target all controls (WPF Styles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131034/how-to-target-all-controls-wpf-styles)
but can not make it work.

I must be doing some very simple mistake but can not figure out what.

I would like to set the TextOptions.TextFormattingMode to Display of all controls on my form. However it is not applied (text is blurry on all controls with the xaml below). If I add TextOptions.TextFormattingMode to all controls then it is fine)

```
<Window x:Class="WPFFrst.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFFrst"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
    </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="463*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="57*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="272*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Margin="197,133,0,0" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Text="Select a message option and then choose the Display button." 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                   FontSize="12"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <RadioButton 
            x:Name="HelloButton" 
            Content="Hello" 
            IsChecked="True"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Margin="217,196,0,0"/>
        <RadioButton 
            x:Name="GoodByeButton" 
            Content="Good Bye" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            Margin="409,194,0,0"/>
        <Button 
            x:Name="button" 
            Content="Display" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="288,255,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Isn't that just <Window ….
   TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"

Comment: Please note that a default Style is only applied to elements with types that exactly match the Style's TargetType. Here, instances of `Control`, but not of derived types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set this property on the window and it will be inherited by all child controls.

You can make a global style for this

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="ClearType" />
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this on your main Window or on any derived class, you could call this at application startup

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingModeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), 
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TextFormattingMode.Display,
 FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | 
FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```