# Is there a more elegant way to auto resize label font size?

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I have a WPF UI with several labels and other controls. I want the size of the texts inside the labels to scale with the window size.

Putting the label inside a Viewbox does what I want, but I feel putting every label inside it's own Viewbox is a bit "uncomely".

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
    <Label>PA-Nummer</Label>
</Viewbox>
```

Is there a Xaml-only (working with MVVM pattern) approach to do this more efficiently?

Comment: You could make an implicit `Style` for  the `Label`-`Control` with a `ViewBox` in the `Template`.

Comment: You could put the entire contents of the window in a viewbox. This seems a bit of an unusual requirement, by the way.

Comment: @Andy Works like a charm. Thanks. Why is it an unusual requirement that the texts scale with the window?

Comment: Does that happen as you scale this page? Or word or excel.... or pretty much anything? It's the sort of thing happens with graphics apps but not so much with business ones.

Comment: Well, it is an app for production workers and all elements should be visible at all time without the need of scrolling and the elements should be as big as possible. I see what you mean, in day-to-day desktop apps this might indeed be uncommon, but in Industry and production frontends it wouldn't be the first time I'd see such a behavior.

Answer (score -2):

If you want the entire contents to scale (not just the text), you could do something like the following. Assuming your top-level control of your `Window` (named `MyWindow`) is a `Grid`, here's the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:WindowWidthToScaleConverter x:Key="WindowWidthToScaleConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform
            ScaleX="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MyWindow, Converter={StaticResource WindowWidthToScaleConverter}}"
            ScaleY="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MyWindow, Converter={StaticResource WindowWidthToScaleConverter}}"
            />
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <!-- Contents -->
</Grid>
```

Here's the converter, which assumes a width of 640 is the normal (1:1) scale:

```
public class WindowWidthToScaleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double width)
            return width / 640.0;
        return 1.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Update**: However, the above solution will only make the font size (and controls) *appear* bigger, but it won't actually change the font size. If you just want to change the font size of `Label` controls, you can do the following in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:WindowWidthToFontSizeConverter x:Key="WindowWidthToFontSizeConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter
            Property="FontSize"
            Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MyWindow,
                Converter={StaticResource WindowWidthToFontSizeConverter}}"
            />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="Name:" />
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

The converter assumes that a width of 640 corresponds to a font size of 12.0 and scales accordingly:

```
public class WindowWidthToFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double width)
            return 12.0 * width / 640.0;
        return 12.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can add similar `Style` resources to scale the font sizes of other controls. But even though controls derive from the `Control` class, you can't define a `Style` for all controls this way. However, there's a workaround for this explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133971/1383366).

Comment: I tried it, but the font size of the texts of the labels stays the same.

Comment: Yes, the appearance of the font size scales, but the actual `FontSize` stays the same. I've updated my answer with a solution that scales the `FontSize`.

Comment: Sorry, I worded my comment badly. I meant, that it also doesn't appear bigger on the screen. However, the proposed solution of Andy in the comments of my OP did the trick. Thank you nonetheless.